# Unity, interior poly always missing in clothing

Tags: unity, mesh, 3dsmax, import

I've modeled interior polygons but for some reason they do not show up in Unity. I've tried changing import settings for normals to both calculate and import... How do you have a tshirt's interior poly show up?

[image]

Comment: Most likely your interior quads have their normals pointing in the wrong direction. You should be able to flip them in which ever modeling program you used to create the model. I would personally avoid double sided shading unless you need all polygons to display on both sides due to the extra performance cost. The cost isn't particularly high but still it's best to avoid it if you don't really needed it. The reason your import and calculate don't seem to make a difference is because the calculated normals are the same as the imported ones and the imported ones are backwards.

Comment: i have tried to flip normal but it does not seem to work...

Comment: Can you post a picture of your normals in your modeling program to verify they look right? The program you are using should show a little axis on each face making it easy to tell they have been generated properly.

Comment: It's not the direction of the normals that determine whether to draw the face, it's the winding order of the vertices. Recalculating the normals resets the normals to match the winding, it won't change the winding to match the normals. You'll want to correct that in your 3D modelling software.

Comment: it shows up properly in 3ds max...

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the normals must be flipped on those polygons. At any rate, unless you really need a second layer of polygons for some reason that I can't grasp from your post, you don't need them: a single layer is enough, just use a two-sided shader for it.

To enable two-sided rendering change to render face both on your material:
[image: Double seded rendered]

Comment: well the shirt should not be see-thru in the back. what else can be done other than add polygons on the interior?

Comment: also i've tried normals flipped.. does not seem to work

Comment: Just use a 2 sided shader

Comment: I just added the image to my answer to show how to make your material two-side rendered ;)

Comment: Note that this is inefficient if you only need to do this for the neckline of the shirt, done it will essentially needlessly double the number of polys that need to be processed at at least one step of the process.

Comment: hmm that RenderFace magic trick is only available for URP... what if you are not using URP?

Comment: For that, you can write your own using ShaderLab. The simplest way is to make a copy of the Standard shader adding Cull Off as first instruction. Get the Built-in shaders source from here: https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive?_ga=2.25705725.1750830837.1603296145-1294758123.1579039644 so you can easily create your double-sided Standard Shader.

Comment: can you provide a solution?